# How to get goal position out of ompl::base *goalptr?

Tags: c++, ompl

I am using [ompl](https://ompl.kavrakilab.org/namespaceompl.html) for path planning in 3D. Please guide how to get goal position (x, y, z) out of goal pointer received from this line.

```
const ob::Goal *Goalptr = pdef->getGoal().get();
```

where `pdef` is problem definition. and `ob` is `ompl::base` Path planner is planning paths but I can't get this goal out of it.

How should I do something like this:

```
x= Goalptr[0];
y= Goalptr[1];
z= Goalptr[2];
```

Or should i cast this `Goalptr` in some other type first and then do that. Pls help.

Comment: The opml page on goals (https://ompl.kavrakilab.org/goalRepresentation.html) seems to indicate that a goal is not necessarily a position, but an abstract definition of how if you satisfy a condition of having reached the goal.

Comment: ok so we cannot get goal position from problem definition? As this (https://ompl.kavrakilab.org/classompl_1_1base_1_1ProblemDefinition.html#a71e20eb387a023333f34b6761a01c64f) says, it returns the goal.

Comment: I never used ompl, so I don't know. From a quick search `State` might be more helpful: https://ompl.kavrakilab.org/workingWithStates.html#stateOps

Answer (score 0):

So [this](https://bitbucket.org/ompl/ompl/issues/360/accessing-the-values-of-the-goal) post helped me to solve the problem. I used this code to get goal position.

```
std::vector<double> reals;
space->copyToReals(reals, pdef->getGoal()->as<ob::GoalState>()->getState());
```

Then we get goal position (x,y,z) in (reals[0], reals[1](https://bitbucket.org/ompl/ompl/issues/360/accessing-the-values-of-the-goal), reals[2]).

Thanks Christopher Oezbek and others who tried.